# Unable to access multiple nodes of model object in handlebarjs template

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have posted my code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sachin1989/x9LRv/6/).

Here i am trying to access data of inner node of fixture but it is not working and it is showing blank results.
template code :

```
<ul>
{{#each item in model}}
    {{#each item in item.list}}
        {{#each item in item.contents}}
            <li>{{item.product_name}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

Can anyone tell me how to access data of inner node of object in template using each helper?

I have updated my code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sachin1989/qgCp7/2/).
Here i am getting data of first node of `home_products` i.e.

```
    "contents": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "product_name": "abc11"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "product_name": "abc12"
        }
    ]
```

Failed to get data of second node i.e.

```
    "contents": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "product_name": "abc21"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "product_name": "abc22"
        }
    ]
```

every time i am getting same data i.e. data of first node.
Can any one help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your template name to `index` to match the route where the data is returned by `model` hook:

```
// that route belongs to index template
Astcart.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Astcart.Application.find();
  }
});
```

Just change the template to:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
```

And change the mapping of the `Astcart.Contents` to `product_name` instead of `name`. To match with your fixture:

```
Astcart.Contents = Ember.Model.extend({
  product_name: Ember.attr()
});
```

Fixtures:

```
...
"contents": [
  {
    "product_name": "abc",
  },
  {
    "product_name": "pqr",
  }            
]
...
```

Working example http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/NKTcc/

Comment: Rodrigues Correa : I have updated my code here (http://jsfiddle.net/sachin1989/qgCp7/2/).Here,every time i am getting same data i.e. data of first node. Can any one help me to solve this issue? I have update my question for this issue.